# Rails: using nested named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

routes.rb:

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :activitylogs
end
```

rake routes:

```
...
                     POST /jobs/:job_id/activitylogs(.:format)          {:controller=>"activitylogs", :action=>"create"}
new_job_activitylog  GET  /jobs/:job_id/activitylogs/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"activitylogs", :action=>"new"}
edit_job_activitylog GET  /jobs/:job_id/activitylogs/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"activitylogs", :action=>"edit"}
...
```

How do I use the route `new_job_activitylog`?

Doing `<%= new_job_activitylog %>` gives undefined exception - so does using `link_to` which most of the examples I see are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
<%= new_job_activitylog_path %>
```

or

```
<%= new_job_activitylog_url %>
```

`_path` returns a relative path, while `_url` returns a complete url including `http://domain.com` if you've set it in your config.

Answer (score 0):

To use those route names, I just had to append `_path` to them.

So: `new_job_activitylog` is undefined, but `new_job_activitylog_path` is a method in the view that takes the job id as a parameter.

```
<%= link_to 'new', new_job_activitylog_path(:job_id => @job.id) %>
```

works!